# Laravel 3 Bundle Routing Variables Failing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3, laravel-routing

We want to make our web service API more RESTful, so I'm trying my hand at routing variables. It seems simple, but I'm getting a 404 error...

It's a Laravel 3 project, and I'm trying to define a new route.
Right now, our URL's look like: `api/object/v1/find?some=thing&another=thing`.

My goal is to have them look more like: `API/v2/objects/{numericID}`.

Everything works fine when testing with this...

```
<?php

Route::get('v2/companies', function() {

return 'Hello';

});
```

This too...

```
Route::get('v2/companies/id', function( $id = 5678 ) {
    return print_r($id, TRUE);;
});
```

But when I try:

```
Route::get('v2/companies/{id}', function( $id = 5678 ) 
{
    return print_r($id, TRUE);
});
```

..it all goes to hell.
Calling a URL like `\api\v2\companies\1234` throws a 404.

What gives??

Comment: Try `v2/companies/(:num)` - using this syntax (`{id}`) isn't how you set variables in routes in L3 (as far as I can remember)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the set wildcard patterns for routes in Laravel 3...

Forcing a URI segment to be any digit:

```
Route::get('user/(:num)', function($id)
{
    //
});
```

Allowing a URI segment to be any alpha-numeric string:

```
Route::get('post/(:any)', function($title)
{
    //
});
```

Catching the remaining URI without limitations:

```
Route::get('files/(:all)', function($path)
{
    //
});
```

Allowing a URI segment to be optional:

```
Route::get('page/(:any?)', function($page = 'index')
{
    //
});
```

Comment: **AH-FREAKIN-HA!! =D** Thanks-a-bunch. I was going off of the example at [http://daylerees.com/codebright/basic-routing] ... maybe that's for L4.